# Magento 2 Admin doesn't work after migrate from one server to another server

Tags: magento2.3, admin-panel, migration

After transfer from one server to another server.
I am not able to access the admin panel. I am getting below error.
[image]

Comment: I think you're just missing CSS and javascript there, try to delete the usual folders like caches, generated and compile and deploy everything, something like rm -rf pub/static/*; 
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*;
rm -rf generated/*;
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I run all the commands but still I am facing same issue.
During static contend deploy I get errors:
Compilation from source: /public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Comment: During static contend deploy I get errors:
Compilation from source: /public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
Compilation from source: public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/web/css/footer-mobile.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Comment: open app/etc/di.xml and find :- `symlink` replace into `Copy`

Comment: I already did but still facing same issue.

Comment: Check in magento 2 root .htaccess file are missing or not?

Comment: .htaccess file is not missing.